# Linear algebra questions

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

$M$ and $N$ subspaces of $V$. Give examples of $M$ and $N$ such that $M\cup N$ and $M\setminus N$ are not subspaces.

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: yes but I cant find anything

Comment: Ok, then give us an example of an $M$ and $N$ that you've tried, and explain where things go wrong. You will get much better responses on this site if you can convince people that you actually want to learn rather than have us do all of your homework for you.

Comment: you should rather wonder what, if any, conditions would have to be satisfied for a set-theoretic operation to respect an algebraic property.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

- Take any subspaces $M$ and $N$ of $V$ such that $M\not\subset N$ and $N\not\subset M$ and then $M\cup N$ isn't a subspace of $V$(why?)
- Any subspace contains the zero vector.

Answer (score 2):

Take $V = (R^2,+)$, and $M = \{(x,0): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and $N = \{(0,y): y \in \mathbb{R}\}$. To see that $M\cup N$ is not a subspace, take $(1,0) \in M, (0,1) \in N$, then $(1,0)+(0,1) = (1,1) \not \in M\cup N$, and also $M\setminus N$ is not a subspace since $(0,0) \not \in M\setminus N$